# Get Time of ScheduledJob Trigger

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to just get the Time of a ScheduledJob Trigger?

I run the following command:

```
$jobTrigger = Get-ScheduledJob -Name MyJob | Get-JobTrigger
```

And the contents of $jobTrigger becomes:

```
ID  Frequency  Time                  DaysOfWeek  Enabled
--  ---------  ----                  ----------  -------
1   Once       2/8/2014 11:59:00 AM              True
```

What I need to do is just capture the value of the time column in a variable so it looks something like this:

```
PS > $time
2/8/2014 11:59:00 AM
```

Note: There will always only be one row in $jobTrigger

Answer (score 1):

You already have the time, it's an element of $jobTrigger. You just need to reference:

```
$jobTrigger.Time
```

Or, if having all of the elements really bothers you I suppose you could select only the Time property when assigning $jobTrigger ala:

```
$jobTrigger = (Get-ScheduledJob -Name MyJob | Get-JobTrigger).time
```

Sorry, I didn't realize that Time was a calculated response. Use the At property.

```
$jobTrigger.at
```

or

```
$jobTrigger = (Get-ScheduledJob -Name MyJob | Get-JobTrigger).at
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party once more, but I ran across this while searching similar questions.

I found this will work as the OP requires.  It will select the Name of the scheduled Job plus the Job-Trigger's time.

`Get-ScheduledJob | Select Name,@{Name="Time";Expression={(Get-ScheduledJob | Select -ExpandProperty JobTriggers).At}}`

Use `Get-ScheduledJob | Select -ExpandProperty JobTriggers | Select -Property *` to check the NoteProperty for `AT`